# Clipping raster layer using vector polygon as mask in qgis

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, vector, clip

I wish to clip an area out of a raster layer for further processing based on a previously created vector polygon layer. Thus vector being the mask for the raster layer.
I am on QGIS.

I tried `Raster`>`Extraction`>`Clipper` but the outcome was a black layer.

Is there a standard procedure for this task?

Comment: The procedure seems correct... Did you use some particular option/parameter?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I left all parameters/options as default

Comment: That's weird... Are you sure that your input files have the same CRS? Can you provide them or a sample of them?

Comment: i get the following warning when executing : Warning 1: Ring Self-intersection at or near point 3868 1762.0000000000582
ERROR 1: Cutline is not valid after transformation. Is there a way to attach the data here?

Comment: Do you have touching polygons on the clipping layer? There was an issue with them, fixed lately

Comment: You may paste a link from an esternal storage service...

Comment: https://mab.to/lj9ZMRUWb

Comment: https://mab.to/PeqaLmnC9

Comment: The first one is the shapefile, 2nd one the raster image. Much thanks for having a look.

Comment: I regret to inform you that there is a geometry error in your shapefile. Try to run the **Check Validity** tool and you will see it from the point vector output named `Error output`. You need to fix it before using the Clipper tool.